# How can I align a progress indicator to the right of a label and keep the label centred in a VStack in SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I want to display a label in the centre of a view with a progress indicator to the right of the label.  How can I do this in SwiftUI on macOS?

The code below aligns the HStack in the centre of the VStack but I want the text centered and the progress indicator aligned with the text's trailing edge.  I guess I could replace the HStack with a ZStack but it's still not clear how one aligns two controls to each other or how one prevents the container from be centered by its container.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AlignmentTestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
            HStack {
                Text("Some text")
                ActivityIndicator()
            }
        }.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .background(Color.pink)
    }
}

struct AlignmentTestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AlignmentTestView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible approach (tested replacing ActivityIndicator with just circle).

Used Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 / macOS 10.15.4

[image: demo]

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Some text")
                .alignmentGuide(.hAlignment) { $0.width / 2.0 }
            ActivityIndicator()
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: 
           Alignment(horizontal: .hAlignment, vertical: VerticalAlignment.center))
    .background(Color.pink)
}

extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum HAlignment : AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return d[HorizontalAlignment.center]
        }
    }

    static let hAlignment = HorizontalAlignment(HAlignment.self)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using macOS so I get an error complaining about '.hAlignment'

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald, it's custom - I just forgot to added it. This code should not depend on platform.

Comment: It works but can you explain how it works - I am completely mystified!  It looks to me like it is shifting the VStack's horizontal position so that the text is centred but anything else in the VStack now be offcentre.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald, Container set preferred alignment guide (in this case custom hAlignment to pass it through internals) and Text uses the same alignment to fit to externally set in container. [Here is a good article about alignment guides](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/)

Comment: I've read that article but haven't been able to make the paradigm shift.  In the solution above why is the frame alignment set on the VStack and how does that relate to the Text alignment guide closure ?